# Use of FB.ui with method permissions.request opens popup

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am working on a Facebook IFrame app and using FB.ui to display the permissions request dialog using the JS SDK.
Here is the code I`m using:

```
FB.ui(
            {
                method: 'stream.publish',
                message: '',
                attachment: {
                    name: 'תחרות התחפושות הגדולה של לגדול',
                    caption: '',
                    media: [{ 'type': 'image', 'src': 'http://www.p-art.co.il/ligdol_purim/logo.gif', 'href': 'http://apps.facebook.com/ligdolpurim/', 'width': '101', 'height': '84'}],
                    description: ('פורים 2011'),
                    href: 'http://apps.facebook.com/ligdolpurim/'
                },
                action_links: [
                    { text: 'Ligdol Purim', href: 'http://apps.facebook.com/ligdolpurim/' }
                ],
                user_prompt_message: 'פרסם את השתתפותך בתחרות'
            },
            function(response) {
                alert(response.post_id);
            });
```

}

A happy surprise is that the SDK knows to show the dialog only for the missing permissions (if any). The problem is that a new IE window pops up and then disappears before the dialog is shown inside an iframe.

I have tried several variations on this code I found all over the net and all of them give me this popup before showing the dialog.

Comment: Update: This happens only in IE (thanks Microsoft). In Chrome and Firefox it works as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had not considered that in order to open a facebook lightbox, you actualy need to be on facebook. I was testing my IFrame outside facebook. When I began testing the app inside a page tab, I got the lightbox. Ya learn something new everyday.